# Where are the files in your deployment package located when your aws lambda function executes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've included a few files in my deployment package that I want to access from within my main handler function. Where will they be located when my lambda function executes?

The documentation says your function can write locally to /tmp/ but it doesn't say anything about where your deployment package files are placed.

Answer (score 1):

Your deployment package files are accessible within the /var/task directory.

---

Steps to answer: I included the following files in my deployment package:

1. handler.js
2. emptyJS.js
3. emptySvg.svg
4. package.json

   ```
   //handler.js
   const fs = require('fs')

   module.exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
       let tmp = "/tmp/";
       console.log(tmp);

       let files = fs.readdirSync(tmp);
       files.forEach(file => {
           console.log(file);
       });

       tmp = process.cwd();
       console.log(tmp);
       files = fs.readdirSync(tmp);
       files.forEach(file => {
           console.log(file);
       });
   }
   ```

My files appeared under the current working directory which was /var/task